# When using json_normalized, keep getting a json TypeError

Tags: json, pandas

How come I keep getting **Type Error: string indices must be integers** ?

code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = json.dumps(result, indent=4)
FIELDS = ["address", "balance"]
df_norm = json_normalize(data["accounts"])

print(df_norm[FIELDS])
```

JSON structured like this:

```
{
    "accounts": [
        {
            "address": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead",
            "balance": "64714244635198"
        },
        {
            "address": "0x00000000af5a61acaf76190794e3fdf1289288a1",
            "balance": "29416569893502257"
        }
]
```

I'm using this article as a guide: https://medium.com/swlh/converting-nested-json-structures-to-pandas-dataframes-e8106c59976e

Comment: What about `pd.DataFrame(data['accounts'])`

Comment: It turns up with the same error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Then the structure of your data is not as described

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `record_path` argument. I'm using pandas version 1.1.0:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['accounts'])
print(df)

                                      address            balance
0  0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead     64714244635198
1  0x00000000af5a61acaf76190794e3fdf1289288a1  29416569893502257
```

Comment: I'm still getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`